# How to build UI Framework using Java

Tags: java, layout, containers

Please help me create my own custom layout, container, component, layout manager...
Example: 
Containers and Layout Managers

- Create a window frame.
- Nest panels within a frame for better layout control.
- Create and display buttons in a panel.
- List two component attributes that are controlled by a layout manager.
- Set the layout manager for a container.
- Place components in a panel using BorderLayout, GridLayout, and FlowLayout.
- Name one advantage of each of the layout managers.
- Create panels with titles.

i was search on google but can't find any that match my requirement

Thanks for your help
Edit: I was found with keyword "Open Source UI"

**Updated: 31, Oct 2016**
I would like to updated some information to make it clearly for someone who concern. Back in 6 years ago what i want to know is how to build "UI Framework" from beginning.

If you have interesting like me i would like recommend Android UI Framework is good start because of open source and well document. Enjoy deep dive in to legacy code :) Good luck

Comment: What's so special about your requirements that none of the existing layouts is good for you?

Comment: "Name one advantage of each of the layout managers." - your title doesn't match your "requirements" - and your "requirements" look like homework questions.

Comment: @Carlos Tasada, Nate: i just want to know how to build simple API like swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create a window frame

```
new JFrame();
```

> Nest panels within a frame for better layout control

```
final JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
final JPanel innerOne = new JPanel();
jframe.add(innerOne);
innerOne.add(otherComponents);
```

> Create and display buttons in a panel

```
innerOne.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
```

> List two component attributes that are controlled by a layout manager

Obviously check out JavaDoc of BorderLayout: `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `SOUTH`

> Set the layout manager for a container

```
innerOne.setLayout(...);
```

> Place components in a panel using BorderLayout, ...

Just apply the layout, and `add` providing the arguments for the LayoutManager:

```
innerOne.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
innerOne.add(..., BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

> Name one advantage of each of the layoutmanager.

Check out the JavaDoc's. They are really helpful in these situations.

> Create panels with titles.

```
innerOne.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Hello World"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, can your refer any resource 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following set of tutorials: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/.

Comment: Thanks for your link, i am reading:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/